# PreferenceFragmentCompat style is broken after setting targetSdkVersion to 28.

Tags: android

Hey there my PreferenceFragmentCompat looked fine before I upgraded to sdk version 28. However after upgrading, its style is broken and I can't seem to fix it. Why is the reason and how can I fix it?

This is my app style:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme0" parent="MyMaterialTheme0.Base"/>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme0.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary0</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark0</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent0</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>
```

**Old style**
[image: Old style]
**New Broken style**
[image: New broken style]

Answer (score 1):

[Here are the diff](http://www.mergely.com/aU576bJc/) changes between the **PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material** and **PreferenceThemeOverlay**. Pay attention to new *allowDividerAbove*, *allowDividerBelow* and *iconSpaceReserved* attributes.
I've had to modify my style to match before update like:

```
<style name="AppSettingsTheme" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
    <item name="preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/AppSettings.Category.Material</item>
    <item name="preferenceFragmentCompatStyle">@style/AppSettings.Fragment.Material</item>
    <item name="preferenceStyle">@style/AppSettings.Preference.Material</item>
</style>

<style name="AppSettings.Category.Material" parent="Preference.Category.Material">
    <item name="allowDividerAbove">false</item>
    <item name="allowDividerBelow">false</item>
    <item name="iconSpaceReserved">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppSettings.Fragment.Material" parent="PreferenceFragment.Material">
    <item name="allowDividerAfterLastItem">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppSettings.Preference.Material" parent="Preference.Material">
    <item name="allowDividerAbove">true</item>
    <item name="allowDividerBelow">true</item>
    <item name="iconSpaceReserved">false</item>
</style>
```

and update your *preferenceTheme* to *@style/AppSettingsTheme* value instead of *@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material*

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Preference rc01 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn#1.0.0rc01):

> - `PreferenceThemeOverlay` has been updated to the latest material theme. If no custom theme is provided, `PreferenceThemeOverlay` is used as the default theme.
> - `PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14` and `PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material` themes have been deprecated in favour of `PreferenceThemeOverlay`.

Therefore you can simply remove your `preferenceTheme` attribute entirely to get the default, correct theming if you're not customizing the preferences theme at all.

Comment: Removing <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item> did not solve this issue.

Comment: Are you changing the default text style or anything else in your theme?

Comment: No, my style file is as listed above.

Comment: Also I am using implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'